"add" method for linked list on python
I'm trying to write an add method for linked list on python, but it's not behaving as expected.
class linkedlist:
    def __init__(self):
       self.item=None
       self.next=None
    def add(self,val):
       self.next=self
       self.item=val

This doesn't work. When I create an object:
myobj=linkedlist()
myobj.add(1)
myobj.add(2)
print(myobj.next.item)

gives 2, instead of 1 as I would expect. Where did I go wrong?
I tried to look at Is it safe to replace a self object by another object of the same type in a method? but it's not helping.

What do you mean I never ran the above?

yeah that was a typo

The problem is that you change the object instead adding new nodes.  Each time you assign self to next but there is only 1 instance of the linkedlist object.

how should I change it using the definition given of linkedlist then?

Can you explain more what you mean by "assign self to next"?

pop (and push) are stack operations.  add doesn't belong.  You can implement a stack with a linked list (or an array).  In a stack you remember the tail and next is really the previous element.

I think this appears to be a matter of choosing words.

add is a set or arithmetic operation.  You can call you methods whatever you want.  Future you and others will be confused.

You only have 1 object and 2 references pointing to it. You need to copy the list before adding to it:
from copy import copy

class linkedlist:
    def __init__(self):
       self.item=None
       self.next=None
    def add(self,val):
       self.next=copy(self)
       self.item=val

myobj=linkedlist()
myobj.add(1)
myobj.add(2)
print(myobj.next.item) # prints 1

To clarify:
print(myobj.item, id(myobj))
print(myobj.next.item, id(myobj.next))

with your code:
2 140520931226768
2 140520931226768 # same object!

With mine:
2 140520931224368
1 140519593761456

UPDATE:
First your expectations are wrong, you should get 3 and 2, which are the values left in the list after you popped the head.
To get these results you need to update what a points to. You could do this by adding return self at the end of add and pop methods, and the reassign a:
from copy import copy

class linkedlist:
    def __init__(self):
       self.item=None
       self.next=None
    def add(self,val):
       self.next=copy(self)
       self.item=val
       return self
    def pop(self):
       self=copy(self.next)
       return self
    
a=linkedlist()
a = a.add(1)
a = a.add(2)
a = a.add(3)
a = a.add(4)
a = a.pop()
print(a.item)
a = a.pop()
print(a.item)

But IMO this is rather ugly and I would rather use Allan's approach...

OP hasn't created a constructor to allow it, the required constructor would essentially be a copy constructor...

OP may not care but myobj should point to head instead of the tail for it to be linked list, no?

Why doesn't this work for the pop() method though? (I added a follow up in the original question.)

If you have a separate question, ask in a separate post please. The answer is because of what @AllanWind just pointed.
